# Delayed Read response from SR810 lockin amplifier over Prologix GPIB-USB

Tags: python, instruments, data-acquisition

I am trying to read data from SR810 Lockin amplifier over Prologix GPIB-USB

Here is the screenshot of the shell showing commands and their response

[image: Here is the screenshot of the shell showing commands and their response]

As we can see, the response to the commands is extremely delayed even when the data points are updated on-time.

Also when I am querying something, I am getting reply of the previous query. For example as we can see in the above screenshot, I am getting a response `'8191'` to the query `print(prologix.ask('SRAT?'))` which should ideally have given me `'13'` as a reply as shown in this second screenshot

[image: Second Screenshot]

What could be the probable reason of this delay?

Comment: Would you use a tool like LICEcap ( http://www.cockos.com/licecap/ ) to record the delay? Do you have a link to the command set documentation your instrument uses?

Comment: @JoeFriedrichsen the issue has been resolved, i just had to keep the baudrate of the instrument same as the baudrate of the host. But thanks for the link to the tool to record delay.